# How to find out why Python send_message() isn't working

Tags: python, sendmail

I'm calling `send_message()` in a Python script, but it doesn't work for some reason. I currently have the following:

```
try:
    print "sending message"
    s.send_message(msg)
    print "message sent"
except (SMTPRecipientRefused, SMTPHeloError, SMTPSenderRefused, SMTPDataError) as e:
    print e
```

Running it now, `sending message` is printed, but nothing else. There are no exception details, and `message sent` is never printed. How do I find out what the problem is with the `send_message()` function? Would a generic exception handler help? I've tried looking for a return code or boolean returned from `send_message()` but haven't found anything. Any suggestions as to how to track down the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to a recent Python version?

Answer (score 1):

"message print" isn't displaying because `s.send_message()` is a blocking call. In other words, "message sent" wont print until the `send_message()` func is finished. Try putting a timeout when creating the SMTP object (I'm assuming your using that lib) and then when your `send_message` fails, you can catch an exception. But in the meantime make sure your host IP/ports are correct.

Answer (score 0):

function `send_message` don't have `from_addr` and `to_addrs` arguments.
it should be like this:

```
s.send_message(msg,from_addr=from,to_addrs=[to])
```